# Can we access redux in stateless component in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-thunk

I want to access redux in the stateless components. How to do that. Please explain with an example!

Comment: Have you spent any time with the [react-redux docs](https://react-redux.js.org/)? Please show an attempt. [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: mate ! as @DrewReese said plese read through the docs ! .
there is example in the [read-redux-docs](https://react-redux.js.org/)

Comment: Also want to clarify (if it matters). When you say "stateless component", for you, are you referring to a class-based component with no state or a functional component (also with no state), or either (both)? Some solutions work for both (i.e. `connect` HOC), some only for functional components (i.e. selector and dispatch hooks).

Answer (score 3):

Detailed docs for using `react-redux` hooks. https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks

Here is sample code using the `useSelector` and `useDispatch` hooks.

```
import React from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";

export const Component = () => {
  const value = useSelector(state => state.value);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  return (
    <div
      onClick={() => dispatch({ type: "GET_VALUE", payload: {} })}
    >{`Value is ${value}`}</div>
  );
};
```

Comment: In bigger projects (projects big enough to use redux) `const value = useSelector(state => state.value);` is bad practice, it;s better to use selector functions. Preferably reselect. [Here](https://redux.js.org/recipes/computing-derived-data/) is some documentation on how to do it. They do mention memoization as a motivation to do it but I think code re use and preventing duplicate implementation would be a greater motivation for using selector functions that compose.

Comment: @HMR Valid point, but *technically* that *is* a selector function, albeit perhaps not a very performant one (i.e. no result memoization).

Comment: @DrewReese The problem with a statement like `myVal = useSelector(state=>state.value)` is that it assumes to know where `value` is in state (state.value) and assumes that `state.value` is the type it needs for `myVal`. If you have many containers getting state like this then it complicates things when a refactor changes the shape or type of the state. A statement like `myVal = useSelector(selectMyVal)` delegates the implementation of getting `myVal` to a function, even if many containers get `myVal`, a refactor would only affect the `selectMyVal` function.

Comment: @HMR it is still a function though, regardless of where it's defined, and that is the point. Nothing is stopping one from factoring `state => state.value` into a utility selector function, say `export const selectMyVal = state => state.value;` for re-use & maintainability. Perhaps your original comment was more about the anonymous inline definition being bad practice as repeating *that* in a bunch of components isn't very **DRY**. At the very minimum, a state selector function is *any* function taking the *entire state object* and returns *a value*.

Comment: `Perhaps your original comment was more about the anonymous inline definition being bad practice` yes, that is what I meant. A lot of documentation uses `useSelector(sate=>implementation)` or even define the selector in the same file like `connect(mapStateToProps)` where `mapStateToProps` is not imported from selectors. I have run into problems with this several times in several projects and would advice against doing that or at least give caution when documenting this. In my original comment I should have said "it's better to use **imported** selector functions"

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It doesn't matter if a component is stateless or not. Redux can be used in the same way on both, using the `connect` method provided by [react-redux](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux), which will pass the selected portion of the Redux managed state into your component as props:

```js
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

const mapStateToProps = state => {asProp: state.someField}

function StatelessComponent({asProp}) {
  return <></>
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(StatelessComponent)
```